# Error contenedor e inyección de dependencias .Net Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, asp.net-core, inyeccion-de-dependencias

De antemano les agradezco, se tomen el tiempo para ayudarme, la cuestión es la siguiente:

Estoy haciendo una API en Net Core 6 aplicando el patrón de diseño DI, no tengo mucho en esta tecnología estoy aprendiendo por lo que al ejecutar el proyecto me sale un **error** en la clase **Program.cs**:

[image]

Hasta este punto entiendo que el error es debido a que no le estoy indicando al contenedor de donde inyectar cierta clase en el constructor del controller, ahora si agrego:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPaymentsProcesor, PaymentsProcessor>();
```

A la variable builder, donde **IPaymentsProcesor** es la interfaz que estoy inyectando al constructor de mi controlador, me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este punto es donde estoy atorado, sigo buscando soluciones, así mismo estoy buscando la maera de pasar por constructor a la clase **PaymentsRepository.cs** una conexión, similar a una que hice con net framework:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código del proyecto, agradeciendo nuevamente me puedan orientar.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPaymentsProcesor,PaymentsProcessor>();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```

**PaymetsController.cs**

```
    private readonly IPaymentsProcesor paymentsProcesor;
    public PaymentsController(IPaymentsProcesor paymentsProcesorPr)
    {
        paymentsProcesor = paymentsProcesorPr;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Payments> list = await paymentsProcesor.GetFullList();
            if (list != null)
            {
                Respuesta.Estatus = EstatusRespuestaJSON.OK;
                Respuesta.Data = list;
            }

            return new JsonResult(Respuesta);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Respuesta.Estatus = EstatusRespuestaJSON.ERROR;
            Respuesta.Mensaje = ex.Message;
            Respuesta.Data = null;
            return new JsonResult(Respuesta);
        }
    }
```

**IPaymentsProcesor.cs**

```
public interface IPaymentsProcesor
{
    string? Mensaje { get; set; }
    Task<List<Payments>> GetFullList();
}
```

**PaymentsProcessor.cs**

```
    public class PaymentsProcessor : IPaymentsProcesor
{
    public string? Mensaje { get; set; }

    public readonly IPaymentsRepository paymentsRepository;
    public PaymentsProcessor(IPaymentsRepository paymentsRepositoryCnt)
    {
        paymentsRepository = paymentsRepositoryCnt;
    }

    public async Task<List<Payments>> GetFullList()
    {
        List<Payments> list = await paymentsRepository.GetAll();
        if (paymentsRepository.Estatus == Estatus.SIN_RESULTADO)
            Mensaje = "La busqueda no obtubo ningun resultado";
        else if (paymentsRepository.Estatus == Estatus.ERROR)
            Mensaje = "Ocurrió un error no controlado por el sistema, por favor contacte a soporte técnico.";

        return list;
    }

}
```

**PaymentsRepository.cs**

```
    public class PaymentsRepository : IPaymentsRepository
{
    public string? MensajeError { set; get; }
    public Estatus Estatus { get; set; }

    private SqlConnection Connection;
    private bool IsValidConnection = false;

    public PaymentsRepository(ServerConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection.SqlConnection;
        IsValidConnection = connection.IsValidConnection;
    }

    public async Task<List<Payments>> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsValidConnection)
                throw new Exception("Connection no valid");

            
            SqlCommand command = new("payments_ShowPaymentList", Connection);
            await Connection.OpenAsync();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            
            DataTable table = new();
            table.Load(reader);

            List<Payments> list = Helper.DataTableToList<Payments>(table);

            if (list.Count > 0)
                Estatus = Estatus.OK;
            else
                Estatus = Estatus.SIN_RESULTADO;

            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MensajeError = ex.Message;
            Estatus = Estatus.ERROR;
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (IsValidConnection && Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                Connection.Close();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: ¿IPaymentRepository  y PaymentRepository está inyectado? En tu código de Program no se ve y sin ello no va a poder resolver la dependencia del constructor de PaymentProcessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te explico:

La clase `PaymentsProcessor` recibe `IPaymentsRepository` en el constructor, por lo tanto tienes que agregar tambien `IPaymentsRepository` a los servicios en`program.cs`.

- `PaymentsProcessor` depende de

  - `PaymentsRepository`

Para que el DI pueda usar `PaymentsProcessor`, necesita saber como resolver las dependencias de `PaymentsRepository`

Por lo tanto en `program.cs` tendrias que tener algo como:

```csharp
builder.Services.AddControllers();
//Tienes que resolver PaymentsRepository antes que PaymentsProcessor
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPaymentsRepository,PaymentsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPaymentsProcesor,PaymentsProcessor>();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```

Otra cosa tambien es que `PaymentsRepository` recibe un `ServerConnection connection`, asi que tambien tienes que resolver esa dependencia antes

Algo asi:

```csharp
builder.Services.AddControllers();
//Resolver dependencia de ServerConnection
string connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddTransient<ServerConnection>(x => new ServerConnection(connString));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPaymentsRepository,PaymentsRepository>();
//Tienes que resolver PaymentsRepository antes que PaymentsProcessor
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPaymentsRepository,PaymentsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPaymentsProcesor,PaymentsProcessor>();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, entendido y anotado, me tube que aventar tambien una explicación, la solución ya esta corriendo sin problemas :)

Comment: Genial  que bien que lo pudiste resolver